# how to use lavaan for multiple regression mediation

Tags: mediation, lavaan

I am using Lavaan for mediation as it is very easy to customize your work

but i am confused about indirect effect and total effect in case of multiple regression

Example:

```
model<-"

#Regressions

depress2~a1*sex+a2*age+a3*treat+a4*econ_hard+m*job_seek
job_seek~b1*sex+b2*age+b3*treat+b4*econ_hard

#indirect effect
ind:=m*(b1+b2+b3+b4)

#total effect
total:=(a1+a2+a3+a4)+(m*(b1+b2+b3+b4))

#propapility

prop_med:=ind/total

"

cfa(model,data,se="bootstrap",bootstrap=50)%>%summary()
```

Is summation of coeffeiects true or i have to multiplying it like:

```
ind:=m*(b1*b2*b3*b4)
```

Instead of

```
ind:=m*(b1+b2+b3+b4)
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have four predictors, one mediator, and one outcome. What is the mediation effect you're interested in? You need to specify a focal predictor. For example, if your focal predictor were `sex`, you could ask whether `job_seek` mediates the relationship between `sex` and `depress2`. In this case, the indirect effect would be `b1*m`, the direct effect would be `a1`, and the total effect would be `b1*m + a1`.

As you have specified it, there is no focal predictor, so there is no single question about mediation you can answer. You can ask a different mediation question for each focal predictor (e.g., does `job_seek` mediate the relationship between `age` and `depress2`?) and estimate separate mediation effects for each of them. There is no single mediation quantity you can validly estimate without choosing a focal predictor.